# How does "make fmt" work in generating thrift files?

Tags: go, terminal, thrift

For running and building some goprojects and generating code for thrift files, I was just using `make fmt` from the command line.

So for example a thrift file could be in the folder `root/thriftstuff/a/b/my_service.thrift`

`my_service.thrift`:

```
name someNamespace

service MyService{
   string hello()
}
```

I go back into `root` and I run `make fmt` without any Makefile or anything and it generates the thrift code for me in `root/.gen/go/my_service/myservice.go`. I'm wondering what happens and whats running behind the scenes? Seems like a blackbox

Comment: There has to be some makefile or this would not work. If you type "make fmt" in a random dir it will not work, right?

Comment: ```.gen``` is not a standard path, it should be ```gen-go```, so that fact also points into a direction where it is very likely it is some custom tool that you are invoking.